# Framework updates how long do you wait?

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, frameworks

In a development team how long do you think you should wait to implement the latest stable version of Framework?

I am asking about different Frameworks we are using Zend Framework, HTMLPurifier, jQuery and jQuery UI.

After a release how long do you wait to update your framework(s)?

Answer (score 9):

If it's revision release (x.y.z -> x.y.z+1), you should deploy it ASAP, because it usually related to bug fix. For example [list of fixes](http://framework.zend.com/issues/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&styleName=Html&version=10300) from ZF `1.7.7` → `1.7.8`.

Standard versioning scheme is *«major».«minor».«revision»*. Change in revision number usually means a bug fix. Change in minor version number, means minor change, usually backwards compatible. Change in major version is significant change, that might not be backwards compatible. See also: [Software versioning (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning).

Answer (score 2):

That depends somewhat on if any of the changes in the framework will require code to be reworked or not. If no, there's less reason to put off an upgrade, and it should be done more or less immediately. If yes, the upgrade may not *ever* happen without a more compelling argument.

Answer (score 1):

I usually start updating framework even before it becomes final. But then when framework becomes final I immediately replace pre-RTM version with the final one, make final changes in my application and publish it right away (put it into production).

If you start working on new framework integration only AFTER it's RTM release you risk to complete it and some time later hear that a new RIM was released, which is not good.

Comment: He's not saying that.  He's saying he starts getting ready for the RTM ahead of time so when the stable release hits, he can get started with it right away.

Comment: @Thomaschaaf, no, I usually don't use pre-RTM in production, but use pre-RTM versions during development, which allows put application in production almost at the same day with framework's RTM release.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the latest and greatest of everything.  Whenever I run into trouble, which I very rarely do, it's relatively easy to find what has changed.

Comment: that's just crazy, i wonder what your talking about... those javascript libraries for example change so fast, upgrading almost always breaks something, and if the something is spread over 100's of pages, you've got a problem

Comment: I disagree.  I've been using JQuery quite extensively, professionally, for a year and whenever something breaks it's easy to fix.  But maybe that's just me...